# A possible incorrect application of Law of Large numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, fake-proofs

A friend left this teaser for me. He asked me to first compute:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$$

Using Stirling's approximation (and another method), I got the answer as $0$. Then he gave the following "proof" for me to check:

Let $X_i$ be iid Bernoulli$(1/2)$. Then we have

$$ P\{\text{n out of 2n $X_i$ are 1} \} = P\{ \sum_{i=1}^{2n}X_i = n\} = \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$$
$$ = P\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2n}X_i}{2n} =\frac{1}{2}\right \}$$
$$ = P\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(X_i - \frac{1}{2})}{2n} = 0\right \}$$

Denote $E_n := \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(X_i - \frac{1}{2})}{2n}$

He argues according to Weak law of large numbers, $\forall \epsilon > 0$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(|E_n| < \epsilon) = 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} P(|E_n| =0) = 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} P(E_n =0) = 1$$

Hence the limit must be $1 \neq 0$.

I, for some strange reason, was unable to refute his proof although I suspect that the bug is in the last step somewhere. I would appreciate any help/hints on this.

Comment: Just because $P(|E_n| < \epsilon) \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for each $\epsilon$ doesn't mean that $P(|E_n|=0)\rightarrow 1$.  For instance, suppose $E_n$ were uniformly distributed between $1/n$ and $2/n$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Consider writing that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|E_n| < \epsilon) = 1$ does not imply $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|E_n| = 0)= 1$

Take deterministic $E_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for example.

To answer your question in the comment:

Let $E_n$ be the sum of i.i.d $X_i$. If $X_i$ are continuous variables, then $P(E_n = 0) = 0, \forall n$, thus $\lim_n P(E_n = 0) = 0$

If $EX_i = 0$ and $E(X_i^2) = \sigma^2 < \infty$, then $P(E_n = 0) = P(\frac{E_n}{\sqrt{n}} = 0) \to P(\mathbb{N}(0, \sigma^2) = 0) = 0$ by central limit theorem(Remark that the cdf of standard normal distribution is continuous everywhere, thus we have the pointwise convergence of cdf)

We don't always have a zero limit, since if $X_i = 0$ deterministically, then the limit is $1$.

Btw, since Bernoulli is of finite variance, now we have a true probabilistic proof

Comment: Thanks Liu. On a side note, does $P(|E_n| = 0)$ limit necessarily have to exist or it need not?

Comment: @GautamShenoy For sums of i.i.d. random variables in general, you mean? This is an interesting question (but different from the one above).

Comment: @Did: I understand. I'll give it some more thought. If I don't get it, I'll post it as another question (Unless it's already answered).

Comment: @GautamShenoy I answered for continuous variables and variables with finite variance.

Comment: @LiuGang You want to *prevent* the OP from thinking? :-)

Comment: @Did Well, there is always something to think about. I've kindly reserved the case of discrete variable with infinite variance for OP :)